# Knockout bug?, cannot match comment end

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Cant figure out why this doesn't work?....

```
<!-- ko if: $root.List().length > 1 || $root.AnyNotEqualToSelectedLanguage() -->
    <div>
         <select data-bind="options: $root.List, optionsText: 'displayText', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

the code above generates a **"Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if: $root.List().length > 1 || $root.AnyNotEqualToSelectedLanguage()  "**

while.......

```
<!-- ko if: $root.List().length > 1 || $root.AnyNotEqualToSelectedLanguage() -->
    <span>
         <select data-bind="options: $root.List, optionsText: 'displayText', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    </span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

this works....

anyone with quick knowledge about this problem?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jcHzK/

Comment: Are you placing the <div> tag within a <p> tag?

Comment: yes apperently it was contained within a p tag, but shouldnt the span element also produced an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only valid explanation that I can come up for the first block of code not working is because your code-block might be within a `<p></p>` tag

Eg

```
<p>
<!-- ko if: $root.List().length > 1 || $root.AnyNotEqualToSelectedLanguage() -->
    <div>
         <select data-bind="options: $root.List, optionsText: 'displayText', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</p>
```

Since a `p` cant contain a `block` level element, the browser will close the `p` tag when it sees your `div`. This browser ends up treating it something like:

```
<p>
    <!-- ko if: $root.List().length > 1 || $root.AnyNotEqualToSelectedLanguage() -->
</p>
        <div>
             <select data-bind="options: $root.List, optionsText: 'displayText', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
<p></p>
```

At that point knockout has trouble parsing it.

You can inspect the source generated for the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jcHzK/1/

Its the same fiddle created by @Artem that does not work because the code is now inside a `p` tag.

Your second code works because you have replaced the block element `div` with an inline element `span`

*Some code and para taken from* : https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/346

Comment: thanks alot!, didnt think knockout was so sensitive about the order of elements...

Comment: just a note that in this case the browser intervenes before Knockout gets the elements, so KO doesn't know the original structure (unfortunately).