# Knockout.js misterious data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

I am trying to wireup knockout.js inside some existing application.
Binding works in some mysterious ways. If I use p tag it completelly messes up the binding.
If I use the label tag it also messes up the binding.

For example:

```
<p data-bind="foreach: currentFields">
   <p data-bind="foreach: props">
       <span data-bind="text: type"></span>
   </p>
</p>
```

This is not gonna work. If I change to span it works.
But then I have the problem with a label tag. If I delete label the binding works.

It seems autobinding is completely fucked up if I use anything except plain span.
Is there a proper javascript binding library? Is Angular.js any better in this regard?
Because rewriting all the existing HTML including CSS just to please knockout.js is really no fun at all :)

Sample code:

```
<p>
    <span data-bind="foreach: currentFields">
        <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: type"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: selected"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: props"></span>
        <span data-bind="foreach: props, visible: selected">
            <li>
                <label>Labela:</label>
                <span>
                    <span data-bind="text: type"></span>   
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: type, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" required="required" maxlength="140" ></input>
                </span>
            </li>
        </span>

    </span>
</p>

var Property = function(type) {
    this.type = ko.observable(type);
}

var Field = function(value) {
    this.props = ko.observableArray([new Property("a"), new Property("b")]);
    this.type = ko.observable('text');
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
};

var myViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.currentFields = ko.observableArray([new Field("a"), new Field("b")]);
    this.currentField = ko.observable();

    this.addField = function() {
        self.currentFields.push(new Field("xyz"));
    };

    this.selectField = function(field) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.currentFields(), function(item) {
            item.selected(false);
        });
        field.selected(true);
        self.currentField(field);
    };

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by it breaks?  The bindings work fine inside all HTML tags.  Nesting <p> tags within each other is not valid semantically though.  What does it mean to break?

Comment: It seems that problem is if I put p around span. I have "fixed" the html.

Comment: The problem is not with the `p` and `span`. You cannot have `li` inside a `p` because it is not valid HTML according to the HTML spec (`p` can only contain [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)). See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869466/knockout-bug-cannot-match-comment-end.

Answer (score 0):

Could you havea look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNwnr/) and tell what is not working as expected ?

```
<span data-bind="foreach: currentFields">
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: type"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: selected"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(props)"></span>
    <span data-bind="foreach: props, visible: selected">
        <li>
            <label>Labela:</label>
            <span>
                <span data-bind="text: type"></span> 
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: type, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" required="required" maxlength="140"></input>
            </span>
        </li>
    </span>
</span>
```

I changed this binding :

```
<span data-bind="text: props"></span>
```

into :

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(props)"></span>
```

Comment: For example I changed all the spans that have data-bind to p and the hell broke loose. Another way is to just wrap your HTML inside one p tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have invalid HTML, the browser reformats it before Knockout has a chance to parse it. What were nested elements in your original HTML become de-nested in the browser.

The `<p>` element has specific limitations--it cannot contain other paragraphs or lists or basically any type of block element.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element